# How to fetch start address and size of different sections (like text data,rodata etc)

Tags: linker-scripts

How to fetch start address and size of different sections (like text data, rodata etc) without editing linker script (.gsi) file?

For example I have tried with the fallowing code and it is working fine:

```
_fourk_3 = _rvectors_start; (in linker script file)
```

To access same in code:

```
extern char fourk_3; 
int test = &fourk_3;
```

Test will now contain `rvector` start address.